# c# WPF App.Current becomes null after custom dialog window closes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF application where I have changed the default entry point.

`<Application x:Class="FrazerClient.App" Startup="AppStartup">`

```
public void AppStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Does some minor work before an application window opens.
}
```

The minor work calls this a couple of times:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
  // Custom dialog window is opened
});
```

The second time this is called, App.Current becomes null. I am almost positive is has to do with the custom dialog window closing, but not really sure how to prevent the closing of the dialog window from nulling out `App.Current` when the last window closes.

This also prevents `App.Current.Shutdown()` from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with this code:

`Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;`

Answer (score 3):

Set [`ShutDownMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode) to `OnExplicitShutdown` so that closing the window does not automatically shutdown the application.

You usually do that in the Xaml of the application object

```
<Application x:Class="FrazerClient.App"
         Startup="AppStartup"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
```

Comment: Yeah, I found a couple different ways to do this. My next step is to find a way to implement this into my MVVM DLL Framework now.